# Array size in functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, size

I'm working with some arrays in plain C99 and I need to know their size. Does anyone knows why this is happening:

```
int function(char* m){
    return sizeof(m) / sizeof(m[0]);
}

int main(){
    char p[100];
    int s = sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]);
    printf("Size main: %d\nSize function: %d\n",s,function(p));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size main: 100
Size function: 8
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you pass it as a pointer to the function, sizeof returns sizeof char pointer, not length of the array.

Comment: this is why the length of an array is often passed as an additional arg in c functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays decay to pointers at the first chance they get, thus in `function` all you have is a pointer, which is 8 bytes in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `sizeof(m) == sizeof(char*)`, which is `8` on your platform.

When you call `function(p)`, `p` decays into a pointer and loses its size information.